# Pandas_gbq does not append in order

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pandas.dataframe.to-gbq

I am using VM instance in google cloud and i want to use bigquery as well.
I am trying to append the newly generated report in while loop to last row of the bigquery table every 10 minutes with below script.

```
 position_size = np.zeros([24, 24], dtype=float)

... some codes here
... some codes here
... some codes here
... some codes here

 while 1:
 current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
 if current_time.minute % 10 == 0:
    try:
        report = pd.DataFrame(position_size[12:24], columns=('pos'+str(x) for x in range(0, 24)))
        report.insert(loc=0, column="timestamp", datetime.datetime.now())
        ... some codes here
        pandas_gbq.to_gbq(report, "reports.report", if_exists = 'append')
    except ccxt.BaseError as Error:
        print("[ERROR] ", Error)
        continue
```

But as you can see below screenshot it does not append in an order. How can i solve this issue? Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you reading results?  In most databases (BigQuery included), the row order is indeterminate in the absence of an ordering expression.  You likely need an `ORDER BY` clause in your SELECT statement.

Comment: I was thinking that when a new report is generated it will add it to the bottom line.  Can i solve this issue within python script?

Comment: Your screenshot indicates you're viewing a table preview, so it's unordered.  Wherever you actually consume the data, run a query on the table with the ordering clause.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-simple-app-all has an example of running a query and printing results with python.